# What does =+ mean in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Normally in C++ programming language, the plus means addition, in the example below

```
int x;
x += 1;
```

However in plsql query, I am confused about the same usage. That usage does not mean addition. In that case, what is the meaning of =+ ?

```
Select c.* From alf_numeric a, run_of_id b, tail_of_st c 
WHERE category_id IN(33,36) AND a.flow_id =+ b.flow_id
```

Any idea?

Comment: Both your code sample are strange: The C/C++ code does not properly initialize the variable `x`. And the SQL query constructs a cartesian product with table `tail_of_st`, which is rarely what you want. Are these just poor examples or part of some working software?

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
...
FROM alf_numeric a, run_of_id b 
WHERE a.flow_id = b.flow_id (+)
```

would mean:

```
...
FROM alf_numeric a
  LEFT JOIN run_of_id b 
    ON a.flow_id = b.flow_id
```

---

My guess is that:

```
a.flow_id =+b.flow_id
```

is parsed as the (simple):

```
a.flow_id = (+b.flow_id)
```

and so is the same as:

```
a.flow_id = b.flow_id
```

Comment: To spell it out: the `(+)` is Oracle's (old) syntax for an outer join. But the OP has an `=+` in the query!

Comment: @ypercube: This is close, but not correct. The `+` operator changes the sign of the value if the value is negative.

Comment: @Codo: You mean that `+something` actually means `ABS(something)` ? This is certainly weird.

Comment: @Codo: where does the `+` operator do such a thing? In no language i know of - especially not C++ and (MS)SQL, does it behave like that in Oracle?

Comment: @ypercube: No, you're right. The operator doesn't change the sign. It has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that the '+' part of '=+' is a no-op.  Try running the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (v1 NUMBER);

INSERT INTO test1(v1) VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO test1(v1) VALUES (1);

CREATE TABLE test2(v2 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO test2(v2) VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO test2(v2) VALUES (1);

SELECT *
  FROM test1 t1
  INNER JOIN test2 t2
    ON (t1.v1 = t2.v2)
  WHERE t1.v1 =+ t2.v2;
```

which returns

```
V1   V2
-1  -1
 1   1
```

Thus, it appears the '+' operator isn't doing anything, it's just answering whatever is there.  As a test of this, run the following statement:

```
SELECT V1, +V1 AS PLUS_V1, ABS(V1) AS ABS_V1, -V1 AS NEG_V1 FROM TEST1;
```

and you'll find it returns

```
V1   PLUS_V1  ABS_V1   NEG_V1
-1   -1       1         1
 1    1       1        -1
```

which seems to confirm that a unary '+' is effectively a no-op.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

In your SELECT statement, the clause

```
a.flow_id =+b.flow_id
```

is mainly a comparison. It tests whether the value of `a.flow_id` is equal to the value of `b.flow_id`. So the `+` operator in this case is an arithmetic operator working on a single operand. It turns the sign of the value to positive.

*Update*:

It seems I was slightly wrong. The operator doesn't change the sign. It has basically no effect.

Comment: id is not negative. so there wasn't any comparison like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a typo for the old left join syntax in Sybase, which would be `=*` instead of `=+`.  If that's true, you can rewrite the query in a clearer way using `join`s, like:

```
select  c.* 
From    alf_numeric a
left join
        run_of_id b
on      a.flow_id = b.flow_id
cross join
        tail_of_st c 
WHERE   category_id IN(33,36)
```

Which would basically return the entire table `tail_of_st` for each entry in `alf_numeric`, with a filter on `category_id` (not sure what table that's in.)  A mysterious query!

Comment: The old outer join syntax in Oracle is not `=*` but `a.field(+) = b.field` or `a.field = b.field(+)`

Comment: You're right, `=*` was the old Sybase syntax, edited.  Already voted for your answer, added this one to add a likely explanation.  Other than that the + key is on the same button as the = key :)

Answer (score 0):

In your C++ example, the `+` designates the positive sign, it has nothing to do with addition. Just as you can write `x = -1`, you can also write `x = +1` (which is equal to `x = 1`, since `+` as sign can be omitted - and is, in most cases, since it does in fact have no effect whatsoever). But both these cases are an assignment in C++, not an addition - no actual calculation is involved; you're probably thinking of `x += 1` (the order is important!), which would increase `x` by 1.

In your SQL query, I think the `+` is supposed to have a special meaning - it should probably [indicate an outer join](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/outer_join.html). Although if I read that document correctly, it should actually be `a.flow_id = b.flow_id (+)`; as it is here, I doubt that the query parser will recognize it as an outer join, but will instead just interpret it as a positive sign, just as in your C++ example.

Comment: I think that is `=(+)`, but I can't check at the moment... I suspect the question has a unary plus, much like `where a.age = -b.years`

Comment: No, it's not an assignment. You cannot assign anything in a SELECT statement or WHERE clause.

Comment: still talking about the C++ code where I say it's an assigment ;) "both cases" is supposed to refer to x=-1 and x=+1, but you're right, that can easily be confused with referrring to C++ vs SQL, I'll try to improve the wording there...

Answer (score -1):

I believe that's a join syntax thing. The standard way is to say something like `tableA join tableB on <whatever>` but some DBs, such as Sybase and Oracle support alternate syntax. In Sybase, it's `=*` or `*=`. Postgres probably does the same. From the format, I'd guess a right outer join, but it's hard to say. I looked in the PG docs, but didn't immediately see it.

BTW, in C you'd have `x += 1` not `x = +1`.

Comment: No, the join syntax would be: `a.flow_id(+) = b.flow_id`. Note the parentheses and the different placement of the operator.

Comment: Postgres uses the ANSI `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax and not some proprietary operator like Oracle (`(+)`) or MS SQL Server/Sybase (`=*`)

Comment: I know postgres *supports* ANSI syntax. But that doesn't mean it supports nothing else.